# adding house number google map embed code

Tags: google-maps, embed

I am using the google embed code like this:

```
<iframe width="1170" height="450"  frameborder="0" style="border:0"  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=hereismykey4&q=Curtain+Street,EC2A+3AR&zoom=18" allowfullscreen>
```

This is working but the pointer isn't quite in the right place so I tried to set the address to be 134+Curtain+Street not just Curtain+street however when I add in the 134+ I get a view of the whole wold.

How do I get the proper address with a house number in?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you need to know that the map show in [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide) is came from the [Google Maps](https://www.google.com.ph/maps?source=tldso) itself. So if you place an address in your embed request, make sure that the Google Maps supported it or let say available in it.

If you try to search `134 curtain street`, you will get a response "We could not find 134 curtain street"

So you should use a valid address that the Google Maps provide you a valid a result.

So use this address `"134 Curtain Rd, London EC2A 3AR"` in your embed code to properly view the street that you want.

```
<iframe
width="600"
height="450"
frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=YOUR_API_KEY&q=134+Curtain+Rd,+London+EC2A+3AR&zoom=18&maptype=roadmap" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Here is the [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/bs3qkbhg/1/) that I create.